# Is there any verb for 'yes-man'?

Tags: synonyms

Is there any verb for 'yes-man'? So that we can express as, he 'say yes' with his superior.

Or in other meaning. e.g. My wife is angry now, so it is better to "say-yes" whatever she says :)

Comment: This question reminded me of the Del Monte advert on British TV. [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0x6UwdbVD9Y)

Comment: "Brown-nosing," "back-scratching," and "bootlicking" are verbs for the actions of a sycophant. (e.g. "He was brown-nosing his superior.")

Comment: Someone ignorantly *placating* their boss is never a good idea unless they're both stupid.

Comment: You can always verb the noun.

Answer (score 1):

**Toady**

> noun, plural toadies.
>   1.an obsequious flatterer; sycophant.
>
> verb (used with object), toadied, toadying.
>   2. to be the toady to.
>    verb (used without object), toadied, toadying.
>   3. to be a toady.

"toadying". Dictionary.com Unabridged. Random House, Inc. 11 Feb. 2018. http://www.dictionary.com/browse/toadying>.

Comment: Or in other meaning. e.g. My wife is angry now, so it is better to "say-yes" whatever she says :)